# VBA accessing value from form

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have tried a couple different methods of accessing a value in a form and neither are working for me. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Code 1

```
fnvalue = ie.Document.getElementById("spec_type1").Value
 PNSetup.Range("j" & j).Value = fnvalue
```

Code 2

```
Set frm = ie.Document.getElementsByName("itemSpecDispFrm")(0)
fnvalue = frm.elements("spec_type1")
PNSetup.Range("j" & j).Value = fnvalue
```

I am trying to return the value "Note" from "spec_type1"

[image: html]

Comment: Possible duplicate question [how to get elements inside <form> tag of web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137730/how-to-get-elements-inside-form-tag-of-web-page)

Comment: Have you tried something like: ie.document.getelementsbyclassname("classnameA classnameB ifithasmorethanoneclassname").item(0).Value   reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233887/trying-to-fill-web-form-with-vba-can%C2%B4t-address-element?rq=1